# async function returning an array of promises not the actual array of values

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a function which will take am array of intergers, then it will call an other function which will take one interger and do some check and return a promise to resolve it.

I know that getDataById function is not relly doing async job, but keep in my this is just examples..

This is my code:

```
function getDataById(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (id > 0) resolve(id * 10);
        if (id <= 0) reject("wrong input");
    })
}

async function callService(idList) {
    return await idList.map((id) => getDataById(id));
}

let teamIDList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4];


callService(teamIDList).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

I expect it will return an array of new numbers and some strings inside.
But it returned an array of promises.

Comment: You are not `await`-ing `getDataById`

Comment: Use `Promise.all`. Also, there's almost never a need to `return await` something.

Comment: Because async and return await doing the same thing to make sure return a promise?

Comment: @TianQin, not exactly. `async` does several things, (1) ensures that whatever is returned is Promise-wrapped, (2) ensures that errors are thrown asynchronously, (3) makes `await` available within the function. There is no compulsion to use `await` in an AsyncFunction. `await` is only useful when there are statements following it, or in part of a larger expression.  The `await` in `return await something()` is unnecessary because `return something()` has the same nett effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` doesn't do anything special when you give it an array, it just wraps the array in a resolved promise.

To wait for the promises to settle, use `Promise.all`:

```
async function callService(idList) {
    return await Promise.all(idList.map((id) => getDataById(id)));
}
```

Alternately:

```
function callService(idList) {
    return Promise.all(idList.map((id) => getDataById(id)));
}
```

(Side note: No need for that arrow function:

```
return await Promise.all(idList.map(getDataById));
```

)

Note that both of those do things in this order:

- Calls `getDataById` for each `id`
- Waits for all of those promises to be fulfilled, or for one of them to fail
- If they're all fulfilled, uses the array of results to resolve the `callService`'s promise (remember, `async` functions always return promises)

If you wanted to wait for each call to `getDataById` to complete before doing the next call to `getDataById`, you'd do it with a simple loop:

```
// **IF** you wanted to wait for each `getDataById` call to finish
// before starting the next
async function callService(idList) {
    const result = [];
    for (const id of idList) {
        result.push(await getDataById(id));
    }
    return result;
}
```

(You can also shoehorn that into a `reduce` if you want, but it doesn't buy you anything.)

But I think you want the first code block above, starting all the calls in parallel and waiting for them to finish.

---

You've said in a comment that your boss doesn't want you to use `Promise.all` because it rejects if any of the promises rejects. That's true, it does. If you don't want that, you may want to use [`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead. That's a [Stage 4 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-allSettled) (e.g., actively being implemented in JavaScript engines) which is easily polyfilled.

```
async function callService(idList) {
    return await Promise.allSettled(idList.map(getDataById));
}
```

Alternately:

```
function callService(idList) {
    return Promise.allSettled(idList.map(getDataById));
}
```

The result is an array of objects where the fulfilled promises look like this:

```
{
    status: "fulfilled",
    value: (the value)
}
```

and the rejected ones look like this:

```
{
    status: "fulfilled",
    reason: (the rejection reason)
}
```

Obviously, if you want to transform that array, you can easily do so. For instance, **if** you wanted to return `null` for the ones you couldn't retrieve:

```
async function callService(idList) {
    return (await Promise.allSettled(idList.map(getDataById)))
           .map(entry => entry.status === "fulfilled" ? entry.value : null);
}
```

Or if you wanted to filter them out:

```
async function callService(idList) {
    return (await Promise.allSettled(idList.map(getDataById)))
           .map(entry => entry.status === "fulfilled" ? entry.value : null)
           .filter(entry => entry !== null);
}
```

If you want to filter and map simultaneously, we can slightly abuse [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap): :-)

```
async function callService(idList) {
    return (await Promise.allSettled(idList.map(getDataById)))
           .flatMap(entry => entry.status === "fulfilled" ? entry.value : []);
}
```

Comment: Actually, my boss want me to change Promise.all to async await way.. we think the Promise.all will reject if any of the promises rejected..

Comment: @TianQin - Yes, that's right. What do you want to do instead of rejecting? You may want [`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead.

Comment: @TianQin that's not an either/or situation: `async/await` and `Promise.all` are not interchangeable.

Comment: My boss think async await is better than promise.allSettled...he wants me to create a loop to use await and catch every error and handle them..

Comment: @TianQin - It would have helped **a lot** if you'd mentioned all of these restrictions in the question. All due respect to your boss, it's silly to reimplement the wheel: Just use `allSettled` and post-process (see the updated answer). But if you want to do it yourself, look at the `allSettled` polyfill, it's not difficult to do. But it doesn't use `async`/`await`, because `async`/`await` isn't suited to operations on arrays of promises. That's why we have these promises pimitives `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled`, `Promise.race`, ...

Comment: @T.J Crowder - thank you very much for above very detail explanation. I was using Promise all, I think I will just change it to Promise.allSettled and talk to my boss. Thank you again.